# Preserve SSI (Server Side includes) declarations with gulp-uglify

Tags: javascript, nginx, gulp, ssi, gulp-uglify

During gulp-uglify task, SSI (server side includes) declarations are removed, maybe because uglify() removes invalid blocks of non-javascript code.

i.e.:

mymodule-source.js

```
"use strict";
<!--# include file="/ssi/config.js" -->
window.mymodule = function(mymodule) {};
```

After uglify() call on gulp pipe, it compress file to the following:

mymodule-minified.js

```
"use strict";window.mymodule=function(e){};
```

Expected result for app health, is the following result:

mymodule-expected.js

```
"use strict";<!--# include file="/ssi/config.js" -->window.mymodule=function(e){};
```

There is some kind of filter to declare to avoid SSI declarations being purged from final minified/uglified file?

By example, some kind of filter over regex ]+>

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question.I noticed that uglifyJs has --comment parameter.
 Preserve copyright comments in the output. By
                                default this works like Google Closure, keeping
                                JSDoc-style comments that contain "@license" or
                                "@preserve". You can optionally pass one of the
                                following arguments to this flag:
                                - "all" to keep all comments
                                - a valid JS RegExp like `/foo/` or `/^!/` to
                                keep only matching comments.
                                Note that currently not *all* comments can be
                                kept when compression is on, because of dead
                                code removal or cascading statements into
                                sequences.

But I don't know how to use --comment in gulp task.